# Why is my authenticated NodeJS route returning results with an incorrect JWT token?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have a NodeJS application which I have begun to separate out in to smaller files since the original became a little bloated.

In my index.js I have routes that are protected by a function a freelancer wrote to provide JWT authentication. These routes work as required.

```
app.use(require('./lib/api-calls/convert.js'));

//  Security Enabled index.js
//
const { app } = require ('./lib/deps/init_dependencies.js');
const { enableSecurity } = require("./security");
const main = async () => {

    // Enable API JWT Security = Comment out the line below to turn off security.
    await enableSecurity(app);
        
    app.get('/v1/createSession:key/:limit', function (req, apiResponse) {
        
       // My route, working well

    });
}
main()
```

I've created `/lib/routes/convert.js` and am wanting to write new routes in this file which also require JWT authentication. However, I always receive status 200 'OK', regardless of whether the authentication header is correct or not... I'm using Postman to make my calls. Here's my code:

```
const app = require('express')();
    
//JWT authentication
const { enableSecurity } = require('../../security');
const main = async () => {

    // Enable API JWT Security = Comment out the line below to turn off security.
    await enableSecurity(app);

    app.get('/v3/convertw3w/:locationValue/:countryCode', function (req, res) {
        
        res.status(200).send({ status: 'OK' });

    });
}
main()
module.exports = app;
```

Can anyone spot the problem? I spent far to long on this last night!

thanks

Comment: Please show enough code that would make it least make it easier to see how things are being hooked up, far too much being left to the imagination here.

Comment: @James, the routes are rather lengthy and would complicate the question. Is there anywhere specifically you'd like me to expand on the code?

Comment: There is zero things wrong with the code you posted. Any issues are probably in code you did not post here. I'm guessing in `enableSecurity()` but that's only a guess. Try to remove as much code as you can but still able to replicate the problem ON YOUR PC, NOT ON STACKOVERFLOW. Then once you have that minimal code post the entire not-lengthy code with issues on Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks, but those old routes in `index.js` which also has `enableSecurity()` are working fine. The path to require `security` in `convert.js` is ok to format in the `../../security` format?

Comment: It gets weirder... I put the offending route into `index.js` with the other routes that work well. It doesn't; work there, so I'm stumped.

Comment: OK, found the issue, now just now sure why. `app.get('/v1/....')' works well, but 'app.get('/v3/...')' does not so I'll check with the developer where that constraint is. Cheers everyone

Answer (score 0):

Just some food for thought here and we do something similar, but if you use

```
enableSecurity(app)
```

As middleware on the route and the

```
next()
```

function in the middleware you can omit the need to make this a promise, because middelware is designed to process in order of the middleware and the next function tells express to move to the next middleware.

How we do it, is to have the middleware 'auth', because middleware will pass the req and res objects to each one in the stack you can have all your JWT decode in one place.

We typically will pass the token in the header OR the req object, just depends on the mimetype we pass, so in out auth we check if the token is in the header or the req, if so we decode, if it passes decode we pass

```
next()
```

in that code block otherwise we res.json({"response":"not authorized"})